# How to use Kubernetes kubeConfig to perform API calls in Karate Framework

Tags: karate

I have kube config having client-certificate-data and client-key-data, how can I use this in karate to make api calls?

Is there a way to use these pem certificate in karate to configure ssl keystore ?
Any example for doing this ?

Comment: please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#x509-certificate-authentication - you may need certificates in PEM format. how you get them is up to you